# VB compiling programme

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it hard to compile software so that it is a single .exe file? I have been publishing the program in the traditional manner and the resultant program consists of a setup file and a couple data files. Ideally I would like to have a lone exe that runs program without having to install.

Comment: What kind of project are you dealing with? Building a Windows or Console Project yields an EXE. You need to provide more details

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're using Visual Basic, you'll always need to, at a minimum, guarantee the target computer has the proper .NET Framework installed.

If that's the case, then you can just deploy your .exe from your Console or WIndows Application project, and it will work, *provided* you don't use any references or types outside of the standard framework types.  If you have any assemblies you use, or require any extra data to exist, then an installer is the correct way to go.

In general, building an installer makes sure that all of the dependencies are in place, which is why it's the "traditional" manner of publishing.  Without that, you (or somebody) has to verify the dependencies before running your program manually.